# How do I calculate the offset, in hours, of a given timezone from UTC in ruby?

Tags: ruby, timezone

I need to calculate the offset, in hours, of a given timezone from UTC in Ruby. This line of code had been working for me, or so I thought:

```
offset_in_hours = (TZInfo::Timezone.get(self.timezone).current_period.offset.utc_offset).to_f / 3600.0
```

But, it turns out that was returning to me the Standard Offset, not the DST offset. So for example, assume

```
self.timezone = "America/New_York"
```

If I run the above line, offset_in_hours = -5, not -4 as it should, given that the date today is April 1, 2012.

Can anyone advise me how to calculate offset_in_hours from UTC given a valid string TimeZone in Ruby that accounts for both standard time and daylight savings?

Thanks!

---

**Update**

Here is some output from IRB. Note that New York is 4 hours behind UTC, not 5, because of daylight savings:

```
>> require 'tzinfo'
=> false
>> timezone = "America/New_York"
=> "America/New_York"
>> offset_in_hours = TZInfo::Timezone.get(timezone).current_period.utc_offset / (60*60)
=> -5
>>
```

This suggests that there is a bug in TZInfo or it is not dst-aware

---

**Update 2**

Per joelparkerhender's comments, the bug in the above code is that I was using utc_offset, not utc_total_offset.

Thus, per my original question, the correct line of code is:

```
offset_in_hours = (TZInfo::Timezone.get(self.timezone).current_period.offset.utc_total_offset).to_f / 3600.0
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes, use TZInfo like this:

```
require 'tzinfo'
tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/Los_Angeles')
```

To get the current period:

```
current = tz.current_period
```

To find out if daylight savings time is active:

```
current.dst?
#=> true
```

To get the base offset of the timezone from UTC in seconds:

```
current.utc_offset
#=> -28800 which is -8 hours; this does NOT include daylight savings
```

To get the daylight savings offset from standard time:

```
current.std_offset
#=> 3600 which is 1 hour; this is because right now we're in daylight savings
```

To get the total offset from UTC:

```
current.utc_total_offset
#=> -25200 which is -7 hours
```

The total offset from UTC is equal to utc_offset + std_offset.

This is the offset from the local time where daylight savings is in effect, in seconds.

Comment: Help me understand -- if current_period is aware via dst? that daylight savings time is active or inactive, then why is current_period.offset not taking that into consideration? Is this a bug? Ultimately, I know about all these methods in TimeZone, my goal is to assign the correct value to the variable offset_in_hours

Comment: Please see my output above, from running irb - this suggests that tzinfo is not, in fact, dst-aware, or that there is a bug?

Comment: Not a bug -- you just need to account for the dst. I've added info to the answer about two more methods that show how to do it.

Comment: Is there an easy to convert the result (in seconds) to a string like '-0200' so it can be used in some of DateTime's methods? Or will I need to implement my own converter and formatter for that case? Thanks

Comment: This should be in tzinfo's README