# Ruby/Rails - Convert Unix Timestamp to HH:MM am/pm with Timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, timezone

Let's suppose I have the following data:

Unix timestamp: `1388935522`

**User Timezone**: `America/Los_Angeles`

I currently have the following piece of code,

```
Time.at(1388935522).strftime("%I:%M %P")
```

which converts the Unix timestamp.

What is the best way to use the "**User Timezone**" (currently as a "string") to determine the offset (which would be -8:00) and display the time based upon the user's timezone (7:25 am).

Thanks very much!

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128436/ruby-converting-utc-to-users-time-zone

Comment: Or also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962038/how-do-i-calculate-the-offset-in-hours-of-a-given-timezone-from-utc-in-ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have basically two alternatives:

1. server-side approach
2. client-side approach using JavaScript

I [explained both in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20749338/123527) no more than a few days ago.