# Get UTC timezone offset where hour is X in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a cronjob running and every time the task is run I want to load contacts from my database where the local hour for that individual is the specified hour in my cron system.

For example: give me all contacts in the timezone where it is current the 4pm hour (16th hour).

In order to accomplish this, I want to make a simple function that returns the [UTC timezone offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets) where the current hour is X.

This is the best solution I came up with but figure there's something more efficient.

```
def timezone_offset_for_hour hour
    ["-12:00","-11:00","-10:00", "-09:30","-09:00","-08:00","-07:00","-06:00","-05:00","-04:00","-03:30",
"-03:00","-02:00","-01:00","+00:00","+01:00","+02:00","+03:00","+03:30","+04:00","+04:30","+05:00","+05:30",
"+05:45","+06:00","+06:30","+07:00","+08:00","+08:30","+08:45","+09:00","+09:30","+10:00","+10:30",
"+11:00","+12:00","+12:45","+13:00","+14:00"].select{ |o| Time.now.getlocal(o).hour == hour }
end
```

The solution can be pure ruby or include Rails methods.

Comment: Surely you must have made an attempt to solve this on your own. Please edit your question to include what you have so far.

Comment: show us some code so that we can help you

Comment: @Arvind definitely not a duplicate

Comment: @Aniket will show code in a moment ... halfway through it and struggling.

Comment: I am not sure but it is looking like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962038/how-do-i-calculate-the-offset-in-hours-of-a-given-timezone-from-utc-in-ruby

Comment: @Arvind nope it's not ... ultimately I want a list of offsets. I've displayed the code to where I'm at so far. I want to ultimately have a list of all UTC offsets so this is only partially complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need numerical offsets:

```
offsets = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map{ |t| t.utc_offset / 3600.0 }.uniq
```

If you need the string representations:

```
offset_strs = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:formatted_offset).uniq
```

Comment: I definitely like this because it's shorter with code but is it faster with speed?

Comment: No idea, I was aiming for accuracy (since TZs change once in a while). You can benchmark for your specific flow.